# retrieving custom attribute from input is not working

Tags: jquery, attributes

I've got an `<input>` tag inside a `<table>` with a custom attribute.
When I try to create a function to retrieve that attribute it doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input row="ab01" id="ab01_01">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

function retrieve_row(){
alert($(this).attr('row'));
}
```

The result is `undefined`. Why?

Comment: because what is `$(this)`?  try `$("#ab01_01").attr('row');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

Your `this` isn't scoped right, just target your element directly:

```
function retrieve_row(){
   alert($('#ab01_01').attr('row'));
}
```

Also, don't make custom HTML attributes like you are. Have no fear, though, you can use the HTML5 `data-` attribute to achieve the same end:

```
  <input row="ab01" id="ab01_01">  //INVALID

  <input data-row="ab01" id="ab01_01"> //VALID

   function retrieve_row(){
      alert($('#ab01_01').attr('data-row')); //The un-hip way
      alert($('#ab01_01').data('row')); //Like the cool kids are doing
   }
```

From jQuery's pappy: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Based on the OP's comments, I believe he is looking for this:

```
$("table").on( "click", "input", function() {
     alert($(this).data('row'));
});
```

You might want to add a class or ID to your table so that this function isn't overly broad.

Comment: I think you mean attribute, not element?

Comment: +1 Although using data attributes, you should use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of .attr()

Comment: You both are right on both counts. Sorry, early morning and had blood taken :)

Comment: it is working, but: 1- if I have multiple input tag with different id and different data-row attribute and 2- I make a function onclick that retrieve me the data-row of the input I've clicked?

Comment: Are you looking for a click handler to be applied to each input, which will alert you to its `data-row` value?

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer. Feel free to mark as the correct answer if it has helped you :)