# Update custom attribute from input value shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-sharer

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565342/retrieving-custom-attribute-from-input-is-not-working) has a similar issue as mine. But still, it doesn't help in my case.

I have a textbox where I am allowing user to paste or enter url. And when the share button is click it will share that url on textbox.

```
<div class="sharewrapurl">
    <div id="shareurl_validation" style="display: none"> </div>
    <input type="text" id="shareviaurl_url" class="textbox_with_url" name="shareviaurl_url" placeholder="Paste URL here.">
    <div class="shareurlbutton">
        <span id="fb_ut_urlshare" style="width:100px;"><span class="st_facebook_large" st_url="http://santosh-shah.com" st_title="#DVDNation #ad #DVD20" onclick="social_share_url(appConfig.FacebookPostWidgetConfigId)"></span></span>
        <span id="tw_ut_urlshare" style="width:100px;"><span class="st_twitter_large" st_url="s" st_title="#DVDNation #ad #DVD20" onclick="social_share_url(appConfig.TwitterPostWidgetConfigId)"></span></span>
    </div>
    <!-- /.shareurlbutton -->
</div>
```

If I click directly the facebook share then it will share my domain name that is in `st_url` but I want to update that attribute with input box value.

```
$('#shareviaurl_url').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    var url = $("#shareviaurl_url").val();
    $("#shareurlbutton").find("#st_facebook_large").attr("st_url",url);
    console.log($("#shareurlbutton").find("#st_facebook_large").attr("st_url"));//returns undefined.
});
```

Comment: st_facebook_large is a class, but you're looking for an id in your find function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using id selectors (`#`) instead of class selectors (`.`). Here is working version:

```js
$('#shareviaurl_url').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
    var url = $('#shareviaurl_url').val();
    $('.shareurlbutton').find('.st_facebook_large').attr('st_url', url);
    console.log($('.shareurlbutton').find('.st_facebook_large').attr('st_url'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sharewrapurl">
    <div id="shareurl_validation" style="display: none"> </div>
    <input type="text" id="shareviaurl_url" class="textbox_with_url" name="shareviaurl_url" placeholder="Paste URL here.">
    <div class="shareurlbutton">
        <span id="fb_ut_urlshare" style="width:100px;"><span class="st_facebook_large" st_url="http://santosh-shah.com" st_title="#DVDNation #ad #DVD20" onclick="social_share_url(appConfig.FacebookPostWidgetConfigId)"></span></span>
        <span id="tw_ut_urlshare" style="width:100px;"><span class="st_twitter_large" st_url="s" st_title="#DVDNation #ad #DVD20" onclick="social_share_url(appConfig.TwitterPostWidgetConfigId)"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cheers. :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing my mistake. Its now adding fine. But still that share thing doesn't work with updated url. However I see the attribute is updated. Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know what `social_share_url` does. I can only guess that something could be storing the attr value and not fetching it again on click. Btw, if my answer helped you it, i'd appreciate if you mark it as correct.

Comment: Yes, it did help. Thanks.